# Why the unexpected behaviour for scanf(" %f "... " %f "..." %c ")?

Tags: c

I am trying build a simple calculator. But whenever I input both the numbers, it skips straight to the default case and doesn't take in the input of operator. Here is my code -:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float num1, num2, result;
    char opr;
    
    printf("Enter the first number : ");
    scanf(" %f ", &num1);
    printf("\nEnter the second number : ");
    scanf(" %f ", &num2);
    printf("\nEnter the operation to be performed (+, -, *, /) : ");
    scanf(" %c ", &opr);

    switch (opr)
    {
        case '+' :
                   result = num1 + num2;
                   break;
        case '-' : 
                   result = num1 - num2;
                   break;
        case '*' : 
                   result = num1 * num2;
                   break;
        case '/' : 
                   result = num1/num2;
                   break;
        default : 
                   printf("\nWrong input."); 
                   break;                                           
    }
    
    printf("\nThe result is : %f", result);
    return 0;  
}
```

I tried to take the operator input twice and even left a space before "%c" so that it doesn't take newline as input. It skips straight to "Wrong input." section. Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: Two good habits that you need to learn: Use *trailing* newline in `printf`; And don't have trailing (or for almost all formats, leading) spaces in a `scanf` format (this is the cause of your apparent problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't understand. Please, can you explain in detail?

Comment: When running from a terminal or console window, output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes) is *line buffered*. That means output is actually written to the terminal/console on newline. If you print a leading newline, you write the *previous* line, not the current line in the current `printf` call. Trailing newline also makes sure that the last output of your program will not seem like a part of the command-line prompt, which can happen in some environments.

Comment: As for the trailing spaces in `scanf`. If you add a space, anywhere in a `scanf` format, then the `scanf` function will read and discard any number of spaces (including tabs and newlines). But it relies on there being at least one non-space character in the input, to know when the spaces end. If you have a trailing space in your format string, then `scanf` will wait and not return until you give some non-space input, which will make it seem like your program have hanged.

Comment: Another habit you may wish to develop: check the return value of `scanf` to determine if a value has been successfully read.

Answer (score 0):

The solution (as provided by Some programmer dude in comments here) is:

> don't have trailing (or for almost all formats, leading) spaces in a `scanf`

Your comments indicate that you aready tried and verified that solution,
but have trouble understanding why it helps.

For visualisation, I modified your code without applying the solution, but with adding some helpful output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float num1, num2, result;
    char opr;

    printf("Enter the first number : ");
    scanf(" %f ", &num1);
    printf("Got %f.\n", num1);
    printf("\nEnter the second number : ");
    scanf(" %f ", &num2);
    printf("Got %f.\n", num2);
    printf("\nEnter the operation to be performed (+, -, *, /) : ");
    scanf(" %c ", &opr);
    printf("Got %c.\n", opr);

    switch (opr)
    {
        case '+' :
                   result = num1 + num2;
                   break;

        case '-' : 
                   result = num1 - num2;
                   break;

        case '*' : 
                   result = num1 * num2;
                   break;

        case '/' : 
                   result = num1/num2;
                   break;

         default : 
                   printf("\nWrong input."); 
                   break;                                           
    }

    printf("\nThe result is : %f", result);

    return 0;  
}
```

Try that code with the following input:

```
1.1<return>
1.2<return>
+<return>
*<return>
```

And you get the output (with input inbetween):

```
Enter the first number : 1.1
1.2
Got 1.100000.

Enter the second number : +
Got 1.200000.

Enter the operation to be performed (+, -, *, /) : *
Got +.

The result is : 2.300000
```

This is because:

`1.1` gets scanned into `num1`, but not before a white space and a non-whitespace is found in input. This only happens with the first `<return>` and the first part of the second number `1.2`. So you have to already enter the second number to make the first scanning work, because of the trailing whitespace in its format string. You have to do that before the prompt for the second number, because the prompt only gets to output after the fist scanning is done.

`1.2` gets scanned into `num2`, but with the same problem, this time satisfied by the second `<return>` and the operator `+`. So you have to enter the operator before being prompted to.

`+` gets scanned into `opr`, again with the same problem. It is already need before being prompted for, in order to satisfy the second scanning. It is not yet scanned, it just stops the scanning for a non-whitespace.

Then the prompt for the operator is in output, but at that point it was already required in input, though not being scanned yet.

Then the operator gets scanned into `opr`, but only if it is again followed by whitespace (the third `<return>`) and some non-whitespace (the `*`).

You can see that your program otherwise does as you programmed, yielding `1.1+1.2` being 2.3.

Comment: Until now I only had duplicates for `scanf("%s\n")` in my lib. This is for `scanf(" %f  %f  %c ")` to extend the set. Let me know if there already is a good one elsewhere.